# Question about eliminating parentheses

Tags: modal-logic

Are '□(p → q)' and 'p → □q' semantically equivalent?  Specifically, does eliminating parentheses in the former gives us the latter?

Answer (score 1):

The two formulas cannot be equivalent:

- Consider in the first formula □(p → q) the specific case q=p. Then it
  reads □(p → p), which is true for all p.
- And consider also in the second formula p → □q the specific case q=p.
  Then it reads p → □p, which is not true for all p.

Hence the two formulas □(p → q) and p → □q are not equivalent.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you are saying.  I am sure it is all me.

Comment: @EdwardFreeman I expanded my answer.

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to say. □(p → p) is a tautology, but p → □q is not.  Therefore, the two are not logically equivalent.  Right?  But how all this is relevant to to my question? Besides, your substitution of p for q is ad hoc.  Anyhow, I appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

The [distribution axiom](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ModLog) in modal logic is this:

- □(*A* → *B*) → (□*A* → □*B*)

Later on in the above-linked SEP article, they discuss the expression *A* → □*B* in connection with a proposal called (***B***):

[image]

So they separate the intended meaning of □(*A* → *B*) from that of *A* → □*B*, there.

---

Today, I was reading [an essay that goes over Lewis' counterpart theory at great length](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-020-02720-1), and I noticed that it says this somewhere down the line:

[image]

This doesn't really solve your problem by itself, I expect, but hopefully it can help you with understanding the matter a little bit more!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I am sorry that was not clear in the question that I was asking about the semantic relation between □(A → B) and (A → □B) strictly within the logical framework of the Lewiesean logic of conditional, as in 'not possible p and q.' It seems to me that if we stay within the logical boundaries of this logic, the semantic equivalence between □(A → B) and (A → □B) holds.  Then again, I was not sure, as I knew that the distribution axiom states otherwise.

Comment: Thank you.  I will read the paper.

Answer (score 1):

They are different. If we read the box □ as 'necessarily', then □(p → q) means it is necessarily the case that p is a sufficient condition for q, while p → □q means p is a sufficient condition for q being necessarily true.

Another way to understand the difference is to observe that if we have □(p → q), we need to combine it with □p in order to get to the conclusion □q. But with p → □q we need only combine it with p to get to □q. I.e.

```
□(p → q); □p; therefore □q          is valid
p → □q;   p;  therefore □q          is valid
□(p → q); p;  therefore □q          is invalid
```

To illustrate the difference, if p represents "Jack is a father" and q represents "Jack has a child", then □(p → q) is true. Necessarily, if Jack is a father then Jack has a child. But p → □q is false. If Jack is a father, it is not a necessary truth that Jack has a child. It is a contingent fact about Jack that he has children.

It is easy to confuse the meanings in English because it is natural to place an adverb close to the verb it qualifies. So it is natural to say "If Jack is a father then necessarily he has a child". But the necessity properly attaches to the relation between being a father and having a child, not to having a child itself.

This error is so easy to make, it is often labelled as a fallacy. It is known as the modal fallacy, or the modal scope fallacy.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply.  I was not sufficiently clear in my inquiry.  My bad.  I had in mind the three possible outcomes of removing the parentheses in '□(p → q): a. '□p → □q', b. '□p → q', and c. 'p → □q'.  Neither, it seems to me, is satisfactory.  I had in mind the Lewician double fish hook that reads' not possible p and not q' and is standardly converted into '□(p → q)'.  Lewis was advancing the logic conditionals, and it is with this logic framework that I was posing my question, as neither of the three outcomes is adequate to render the meaning of the strict implication.

Comment: You are correct to say that □p → □q; □p → q; and p → □q are all different from □(p → q). It is also correct that the C I Lewis strict implication is equivalent to □(p → q). The conditional □(p → q) entails □p → □q by the K axiom, and this in turn entails □p → q by the T axiom. The only way p → □q would hold in general is if □q is a theorem, which corresponds to the rather weird modal system Hughes and Cresswell call Ver.